# Why does this error occur on boot?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, slitaz

No matter which Linux distro I try to install, I get this error: 
`end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)`

I tried Debian Netinst and SliTaz on a 32-bit Tablet PC which currently has Windows 10 installed.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us what you were doing: When you installed the OS, When you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, it can't mount the root device.

There are many possible reasons for this. One is that you don't load the initrd that is supposed to prepare for mounting the real root.

You should also check the `root` parameter on the kernel command line. The `1,0` in `unknown-block(1,0)` indicates that `/dev/ram0` should be used. So either you want to use another root or `ram0` has not been prepared.